# How to scale an entire game using java

Tags: java

Hi I am almost finished coding my game in java, but i have run into a big problem.
Scaling - everyone has a different sized screen.

Most of my game is controlled from the keyboard but there is a settings feature where buttons are used.

To fix scaling I plan to simply scale every JBufferedImage up by creating a integer 'scaling'.

This is my first game and i am trying to make it all perfect with encapsulation and correct use of available libraries and to me scaling everything individually the way i am seems like a very improvised method. So i have to ask if there is any "official" method to scale.

Comment: This will depend a lot on how you've done your work.  You could, for example, simple apply a `AffineTransform` to the `Graphics` context.  A better solution would have been to code to real values (actual screen coordinates) rather then fixed/magic values

Comment: I added an answer, but it would be helpful if you gave more details about how your game is coded, including some BRIEF sample code.

Comment: You must realize every single 2D game fakes scaling. Hell, even certain programs like RPGMaker VX(and up) lie about the scaling, and just clip the bounds around the renderable space. My opinion on how to fix this? Don't use 2D. Period. If you want to be serious about this, learn 3D programming and go for  a 2.5D game. It will look better, and "scaling" is done with the zooming of the camera matrix.

Comment: @Krythic That's not true at all and would be detrimental to many (admittedly crappy) games' operation. Of course 2.5D can often be better, but that does not mean that he shouldn't start with 2D with scaling until he gets better.

Comment: @DanielCentore I started out with 2D Java as well; I know this question all-too well. The fact is though, scaling with 2D will drop the framerate down so drastically that it isn't even worth it. Most "modern" 2D game engines still acknowledge this. RpgMaker VX, like I have said, keeps the resolution at 640x480 and clips blackspace around that area when in full screen to match any computer resolution. There is no solution to this problem, except for dropping 2D as a whole and moving on to better horizons. Better explain this now and rip off the band-aid.

Comment: @Krythic I pull off 80fps with my simple Mario sidescroller. Anything above that is just silly since most monitors can't display it anyways. I acknowledge this is not the best way to do it but in practice it's just fine for intro stuff.

Comment: @DanielCentore 80fps with Java 2D(Swing or Awt) is an egregious fabrication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97919/discussion-between-daniel-centore-and-krythic).

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you added some context to help us know how your game works, but perhaps this can get you on the right track. In my old Java game, I simply draw everything to a fixed size BufferedImage and scale the buffered image to the panel size. There are "better" (*ie* more efficient) ways to do it, but this is likely the easiest.

Create a panel:

```
panel = new JComponent()
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        buffer = getCurrentBuffer();  // Get the updated game image from somewhere

        // Figure out how to scale the image
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();

        int[] scale = scaleImage(buffer, w, h);

        // Make sure scaling isn't all pixely
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Clear the screen
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        // Paint image scaled
        g2.drawImage(buffer, scale[2], scale[3], scale[0], scale[1], null);
    }
};
```

Helper function:

```
/**
 * Gets image scaling keeping its aspect ratio
 * @param image Image to scale
 * @param newWidth Width goal
 * @param newHeight Height goal
 * @return new int[] {Width to make it, height to make it, x to draw at, y to draw at}
 */
public static int[] scaleImage(Image image, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    double thumbRatio = (double) newWidth / (double) newHeight;
    int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
    double aspectRatio = (double) imageWidth / (double) imageHeight;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if (thumbRatio < aspectRatio)
    {
        y = newHeight;
        newHeight = (int) (newWidth / aspectRatio);
        y /= 2;
        y -= newHeight / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        x = newWidth;
        newWidth = (int) (newHeight * aspectRatio);
        x /= 2;
        x -= newWidth / 2;
    }

    return new int[] { newWidth, newHeight, x, y };
}
```

When creating the fixed size buffered image, make sure to only create it once as it is very inefficient to recreate it each game loop iteration.

```
buffer = new BufferedImage(NOMINAL_GAME_WIDTH, NOMINAL_GAME_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: Really, what's wrong with `g2.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaledInstance(scale))`.  Scaling is not cheap and shouldn't be done within the `paintComponent` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not sure why that would be any more efficient than doing what I've done inside `paintComponent`, but if you can explain then I would definitely be interested in reading. Perhaps you could write a complementary answer.

Comment: I originally thought that you were scaling the image in `scaleImage`, but you're only calculating the size. I'm not sure that `drawImage` is your best choice, but I tend to use `AffineTransform.getScaledInstance` exclusively.  A "better" choice, might be to scale the page buffer to start with (so it's always at the scaled size) and use a `AffineTransform` on it's `Graphics` context (of the page buffer), assuming they are using this painting process and not a `BufferedStrategy`

Comment: thank you all so much for your help, i think i will simply scale all images and values when the game is opening